# phpmyadmin - Can't login anymore after MariaDB installation

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I was following an online tutorial on how to install a mailserver.

So I ran this command:

```
apt-get install postfix postfix-mysql postfix-doc mariadb-client mariadb-server openssl getmail4 rkhunter binutils dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d dovecot-mysql dovecot-sieve dovecot-lmtpd sudo
```

MariaDB setup screen popped up and asked me to set a password.

After the installation I tried logging in into my phpmyadmin and failed.

[image]

I wish I could turn back time :(

Comment: Try default root/admin.

Comment: Or, if it's an Apple machine, try root with no password.

Comment: Not working. It's a Debian server

Comment: Maybe this link would be helpful https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password

Comment: @AndriiPryimak That fixed it. Thank you

Comment: @LisaCleaver You are welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

MariaDB does not allow to log in from anywhere as root (except root shell). Just create another user and make it super admin.

In shell:
`sudo mysql`

Then:

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Grant all permissions

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'admin'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now, you can log in as `admin` using phpmyadmin.